# How to set sheet create event as a trigger in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to automate the creation of new folders in Google drive when new sheet created in a spreadsheet. And want to change folder name automatically when sheet name changes.

I found onEdit() trigger at [Simple Trigger Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) but it's about 'cell changes' not about 'sheet creates' or 'sheetname changes'.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When writing apps script code in google sheet,
I use `onChange()` event.

```
function onChange(e){
   if (e.changeType=='INSERT_GRID') //sheet create event
   else if (e.changeType=='OTHER') //etc event like sheet name changes, column resize and so on
}
```

There's many other types that detecting sheet changes in `onChange()` event.

EDIT, REMOVE_COLUMN, FORMAT ...

Please check this [reference document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change).